# Difference between $\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$ and the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^e}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-spaces

Q: Let $p$ be a prime and let $e \ge 2$. The quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$ and the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^e}$ are both rings and have the same number of elements. Describe some ways in which they are intrinsically different.

My textbook confirms my understanding that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p}$? are the same thing.

With $\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$, there will be elements that don't have multiplicative inverses, so it is not a field. What is $\mathbb{F}_{p^e}$ if it's not the same as $\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $Z/p^e$ has zero divisors for $e>1$, $\mathbb{F}_{p^e}$ does not have zero divisors. See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813203/what-differences-are-there-between-mathbb-z-p-and-mathbb-f-p) for the difference of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_{p^e}$ is *the* field with $p^e$ elements, and it is not $\mathbb{Z}/p^e\mathbb{Z}$, since the latter is not a field :-) For a construction of $\mathbb{F}_{p^e}$, you may read the notes of Keith Conrad: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/finitefields.pdf